# JavaScript preload Audio

Tags: javascript, audio, html

I'm **new** to JavaScript, but I know, that I could set and play some audio file with this code:

```
player.src = "somefile.mp3";
player.play();
```

Where "player" is id of my audio tag. My question is: how can I preload the song? Because when I click on button, it plays after 3s delay...

Comment: maybe starting and momentally stopping playing will help?

Comment: I have so much songs and ringtones to play... No, it will not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Audio element has [`preload`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_preload.asp) attribute:

```
<audio preload="auto|metadata|none"> // auto in your case
```

Comment: That would be better, but I need the script in JavaScript... Dynamically add song and play it. And when page loads I need all audio files to be loaded. Sorry for my bad English

Comment: And preload attribute isn't supported in Internet Explorer. I need to have full compability with all browsers...

Comment: Preload is supported in IE9: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974759(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio see compatibility table at the bottom of the page

Comment: OK. But what about JavaScript?

Comment: What's the problem with creating tag with javascript?